# How can I compare the row values of select columns with the same columns in another dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, data-science

I have two data frames with headers as follows:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['STATE', 'COUNTY', 'QUANTITY'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['FIPS', 'STATE', 'COUNTY'])
```

I want to create a 3rd data frame:

```
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['FIPS', 'QUANTITY'])
```

Such that each row in df1 will have its state and county values compared every row in df2 until a match is found. Once a match is found, the 'FIPS' value from df2 and the 'QUANTITY' value from df1 will be appended to df3.

Basically, I want a data frame that has the FIPS values and Quantity Values per county / state and the csv that I am reading doesn't come with FIPS values.

The Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
a = [['1', '5', '10'], ['2', '6', '12'], ['3', '7', '11']]
b = [['005', '2', '6'], ['101', '1', '5'], ['201', '3', '7']]
df1 = pd.DataFrame(a, columns=['STATE', 'COUNTY', 'QUANTITY'])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(b, columns=['FIPS', 'STATE', 'COUNTY'])
df3 = pd.DataFrame(columns=['FIPS', 'QUANTITY'])
print(df1)
print(df2)
df3['QUANTITY'] = np.where((df1['STATE'] == df2['STATE']) & 
(df1['COUNTY'] == df2['COUNTY'])
                 , df1['QUANTITY'], np.nan)
df3['FIPS'] = np.where((df1['STATE'] == df2['STATE']) & (df1['COUNTY'] 
== df2['COUNTY'])
                 , df2['FIPS'], np.nan)
```

Has the Result:

```
    STATE COUNTY QUANTITY
0     1      5       10
1     2      6       12
2     3      7       11
   FIPS STATE COUNTY
0  005     2      6
1  101     1      5
2  201     3      7
   FIPS QUANTITY
0  NaN      NaN
1  NaN      NaN
2  201       11
```

I'm looking for something that gives me:

```
    STATE COUNTY QUANTITY
0     1      5       10
1     2      6       12
2     3      7       11
   FIPS STATE COUNTY
0  005     2      6
1  101     1      5
2  201     3      7
   FIPS QUANTITY
0  101      10
1  005      12
2  201      11
```

I am comfortable doing such computations in VBA, C++ and MATLAB however I have no clue how to compare elemental indexes of dataframes in python.

Comment: you can do, `inner join` with `STATE` as key and extract required columns. `pd.merge(df1,df2, on=['STATE', 'COUNTY'])[['FIPS', 'QUANTITY']]`

Comment: @MohamedThasinah can I do that with 2 keys, using both STATE and COUNTY as keys? Never mind that worked. Thanks!!

Comment: ofcourse, you can as both columns are same I didn't mention. for the working example look at @jezrael's answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [`DataFrame.merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with default inner join and then select columns by subset:

```
df3 = df1.merge(df2, on=['STATE','COUNTY'])[['FIPS','QUANTITY']]
print (df3)
  FIPS QUANTITY
0  101       10
1  005       12
2  201       11
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try something like this:

```
df3 = pd.merge(df1, df2, left_on = ['STATE', 'COUNTY'], right_on= ['STATE', 'COUNTY']) # merge the two dataframes with STATE and COUNTY as join keys
df3 =  df3.drop(['STATE', 'COUNTY'], axis = 1)  # drop columns you don't need
df3
```